# .htaccess Internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm moving my first steps in htaccess rewrite url engine and I can't resolve an infinite loop neither know why this is happening.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^newsletter\/$ \/include\/newsletter\/index\.php  [NC,L]
```

It should transform (get the page located at)

From http://blabla.it/**newsletter/** into http://blabla.it/include/newsletter/index.php

What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – that the very first thing you should always do when you get an internal server error, is of course to go and check the server’s error logs.

Comment: There is no need to escape slashes in the Rewrite target.

Comment: Really embarassing. Thanks. Rewrite module was not enabled. Solved!!

Answer (score 1):

Please check everytime, as suggested, server's error logs.

**Rewrite module wasn't active**.

WAMP icon -> apache -> apache modules -> rewrite_module

Thanks to @CBrow and @Starkeen.